# Vaadin 10 TreeGrid.refreshItem refrehes only after mouse click

Tags: treeview, vaadin

I use a TreeGrid in Vaadin 10.
This is the way I set the data for the treeGrid:

```
treeGrid.setItems( customers, Dataline::getChildren );
```

When data is changed, I call

```
treeGrid.getDataProvider().refreshItem( line );
```

This updates the table only when I do a click a different element in the table.
If I do not click a different element, nothing happens.

What's the proper way to update data ?

Thanks for any help!
Thorsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does update happen? Is it from background thread?

If it so, you should use push [Server push configuration](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-configuration.html) to update the UI when new data is available.

Because it looks like update is happening only on the next server request (when you perform some action)

At least, the code you are using looks good and should work otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint!  I think I worked to long using Swing ;-)